# Do dual fuel (or heat source) industrial furnaces exist?

Tags: industrial-engineering

Apologies for the naive question.

Reading [this](https://spectrum.ieee.org/float-glass) article I was reminded that there are a lot of industrial furnaces that work 24x7 around the world burning fossil fuels. Then I remembered that often in Europe there is electricity overproduction in the off peak hours. So I wondered if ever existed a furnace that could generate heat by fossil fuels or electric arc depending on the energy source available and the cost in that moment.

Comment: Did you google your question?

Comment: Where is the "overproduction" electricity put ?